# Problema al hacer pagina web desde R en GitHub. Problema con git push

Tags: r, github, r-markdown

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]he estado intentando hacer mi pagina web desde R que este en GitHub, pero me sale un error de que me pide colocar mi usuario y contraseña, intento colocar contraseña (pensando que será la contraseña de GitHub) pero no me deja siquiera editar. ¿Tienen alguna idea o consejo que me puedan dar?

`git add .` -  `git add -A` - `git commit -m "texto"` - `git push origin master`

el error me comienza desde "git push..." no entiendo bien que debo agregar ahí, estoy siguiendo un tutorial, pero no me deja hacerlo igual.

agregaré imágenes referentes. Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje es claro, GitHub eliminó el soporte para la auténticacion a travez de contraseña de usuario desde el 13 de agosto de 2021. En su lugar debes crear un `Token de acceso personal` que es el que te funcionará para la auténticacion, te dejo por acá el url para que revises el proceso https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: @GmrYael Muchas gracias! lo logré

Comment: Que bueno saber que lo pudiste solucionar. Saludos!